# Can't get top nth records sorted on value in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get the top 5 records ordered on a specific value in Cosmos DB but I am getting stuck at getting the records ordered.

The query is done on the following document:

```
{
    "id":               string,
    "Compliant":        bool,
    "DefinitionId":     int,
    "DefinitionPeriod": string,
    "EventDate":        date,
    "HerdProfileId":    int,
    "Period":           int,
    "Value":            int
}
```

**What i have tried:**

**1st try**

```
SELECT TOP 5 cr.HerdProfileId, cr.Compliant, cr.NonCompliant, cr.NullCompliant FROM (
    SELECT 
        c.HerdProfileId, 
        SUM(comp) as Compliant, 
        SUM(noncomp) as NonCompliant, 
        SUM(nullcomp) as NullCompliant 
    FROM c
    JOIN(SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id) FROM c WHERE c.Compliant = true) comp
    JOIN(SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id) FROM c WHERE c.Compliant = false) noncomp
    JOIN(SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id) FROM c WHERE c.Compliant = null) nullcomp
    WHERE c.Period = 201948
    GROUP BY c.HerdProfileId) cr
WHERE cr.NonCompliant > 0
ORDER BY cr.NonCompliant
```

results in: `Unsupported ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY item expression could not be mapped to a document path`

**2nd try:**

```
SELECT TOP 5 cr.HerdProfileId, cr.Compliant, cr.NonCompliant, cr.NullCompliant FROM (
    SELECT 
        c.HerdProfileId, 
        SUM(comp) as Compliant, 
        SUM(noncomp) as NonCompliant, 
        SUM(nullcomp) as NullCompliant 
    FROM c
    JOIN(SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id) FROM c WHERE c.Compliant = true) comp
    JOIN(SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id) FROM c WHERE c.Compliant = false) noncomp
    JOIN(SELECT VALUE COUNT(c.id) FROM c WHERE c.Compliant = null) nullcomp
    WHERE c.Period = 201950
    GROUP BY c.HerdProfileId
    ORDER BY NonCompliant DESC) cr
WHERE cr.NonCompliant > 0
```

results in: `ORDER BY' is not supported in presence of GROUP BY`

Is there any way to get the data needed or is this just not possible in Cosmos DB and do I need to order the results in code later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sql: `Order by` item expression could not be mapped to a document path. Please refer to the statements in this [blog](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/11/06/a-few-cosmosdb-query-limitations/):

[image]

The second sql:

`Order by` can't work with `Group By` so far,please refer to official statement:

[image]

I suppose that you have to follow the suggestions in my previous case:[How to group by and order by in cosmos db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185057/how-to-group-by-and-order-by-in-cosmos-db,as) you order the results in code so far. Waiting for the plan of above 2rd statement for group by and order by...